# How can I include a nHibernate Criterion against a count of matching records

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

**BACKGROUND:**

- I have Master and Detail tables, M and D;
- M contains orders and D contains order detail with parts of various sizes (S, M, L, XL)
- A given order might contain any number of parts.
- 95% of all orders contain at least one item of size S
- New requirement is that sizes can be added in the future, so hard coding the list for SMLXL no longer works

I am looking for a nHibernate query that returns a list of all orders M that only contain parts with a specific size.

In other words, return all order containing only parts of size S, and exclude all orders that contain a mixture of sizes.

I was using:

```
matching_orders.Add(
 Expression.Conjunction()
 .Add(Subqueries.WhereProperty<Orders>(o => o.OrderId).In(DetailQueryOver(S)))
 .Add(Subqueries.WhereProperty<Orders>(o => o.OrderId).NotIn(DetailQueryOver(M)))
 .Add(Subqueries.WhereProperty<Orders>(o => o.OrderId).NotIn(DetailQueryOver(L)))
 .Add(Subqueries.WhereProperty<Orders>(o => o.OrderId).NotIn(DetailQueryOver(XL)))
```

There must be a better way.  Something like "where count(DISTINCT SIZES) = 1"

But I'm not sure how to implement this in nHibernate.

Suggestions?

Comment: Does NH support the `having` clause yet? You could use a subquery in the where like...`where 1 = (select count(distinct sizes) from...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As dotjoe suggested, I believe `having` clauses are accomplished by stashing a projection in a temporary variable, then using it in both the projection list and the restriction list, though I've only done that with `ICriteria` queries, not `QueryOver`.

Another way to write this query is to use two subqueries - one to represent the size you are looking for, another to represent all the other sizes.  Something like...

```
select *
from Orders o
where
    exists (
        select d1.Id
        from OrderDetail d1
        where
            d1.Order_id = o.Id
            and d1.Size = @size)
    and not exists (
        select d2.Id
        from OrderDetail d2
        where
            d2.Order_id = o.Id
            and d2.Size <> @size);
```

We could take this answer another step further and translate this into a `QueryOver` query, but I don't want to spoil your fun.  Is that enough to get you pointed in the right direction?